# Detach Docker Container Automatically

Tags: docker, detach

Is there any way in which an attached docker container can be detached automatically or using bash script or using any command instead of pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>?

Comment: At least you can configure the keys (https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15666), but script them?